# How to iterate through Hosts in .ssh/config

Tags: bash, ssh

On some of my remote servers I use Git to keep commonly used scripts in sync. I would like to have a local script that I can fire to update all remote servers that that are within one domain range. Here is my pseudo code:

```
for every Host in .ssh/config do
    if Hostname is similar to *.uberspace.de
        ssh Host git -C bin pull
    fi
done
```

How would I do this elegantly using bash script?

Comment: What is ~?  In Bash, that will be your home directory.  In C, that means bit flip.  My guess is you meant a meaning from math: "approximately equal to".  But, um, "approximately" is a little harder to define.

Comment: Right, the code was propably not 'pseudo' enough. Changed it to clarify my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s nocasematch
for word in $(grep -i "^[^#\S]*Host\(name\)\?" ~/.ssh/config | paste -s -); do
  case "$word" in
    "Host")
      type=host
      ;;
    "Hostname")
      type=hostname
      ;;
    *)
      case "$type" in
        "host")
          host=$word
        ;;
        "hostname")
          hostname=$word
          if [[ "$hostname" == *uberspace.de ]]; then
            ssh -v $host "git -C bin pull" # Connecting to $hostname
          fi
          unset host hostname
        ;;
      esac
  esac
done
```

First `grep` in `for` loop is to catch all lines with `Host` and `Hostname`. Then `tr` is joining them all together in one line. Then it's a matter of parsing each individual word.

Parsing each word react on words `Host` and `Hostname` (insensitively when `nocasematch` is on), when these keywords are found, then based on its type they're assigned to `host` and `hostname` variable. Since value for hostname is expected to be the last, we're executing our command there, once hostname matches `uberspace.de`. After we finish parsing of hostname, we unsetting the values, so we can pick up the new one.

To debug the script, run it as: `bash -x ./script.sh`.

Comment: This works fine, thank you. Actually I expected some secret ssh feature I haven't discovered yet, but as long as noone shows up with something like that, I'm glad to accept this as correct answer :)

Comment: @mcnesium I've initially checked for such ssh feature, but I couldn't find any, so it's a bit weird for me as well that you've to parse it.

Comment: I just changed the `ssh -v $host "git -C bin pull"`line to just `ssh $host "$@";` to be able to pass any command to all remote hosts. Brilliant :)

Comment: It does not handle Include directive

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Go library that lets you do this: https://github.com/kevinburke/ssh_config